# VBA Dynamic Range with Values Calculation

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have the following problem:

As you can see in column A we have Dates, in column B there is always a "1" when a year changes from one to the next, I marked it in yellow. In column H are different values and in column I, I want to have only the FIRST value, which is greater (in this case) than 10% within one year (so in the period from one to one in column B). After that I want to have the next first value, which is >10% in the next year so next period from 1 to 1 in column B and so on.

Can anyone help me?

So far I programmed this, but it shows me all values >10% but not the first from each range to each range.

```
Sub ABC ()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
rowCount = 2
    Do While .Cells(rowCount + 1, 8).Value <> ""

    If .Cells(rowCount, 2).Value = 0 And .Cells(rowCount, 8).Value >= 0.1 Then

       .Cells(rowCount, 9).Value = .Cells(rowCount, 7).Value * 0.1 / 1.1
    Else
       .Cells(rowCount, 9).Value = ""
    End If
    rowCount = rowCount + 1

Loop

End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you mean by "the value next to it in columns H is > 5 in the range from 1 to 1". If it is greater than 5, how can it be in the range 1 to 1? Also -- why in the world do you even use the phrase "range from 1 to 1"? 1 is the only number in that range. *Perhaps* would mean something like a range of consecutive rows where the value in column B is 0, but if so you should say so more clearly. A relevant set of sample data that includes values in column H and intended values in column I would help.

Comment: I updated my question, hopefully it is easier to understand now:

Answer (score 0):

It seem the code is error on the cell address

```
Sub ABC ()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
rowCount = 2
    Do While .Cells(rowCount + 1, 8).Value <> ""

    If .Cells(rowCount, 2).Value = 0 And .Cells(rowCount, 8).Value >= 0.1 Then

       .Cells(rowCount, 9).Value = .Cells(rowCount, 8).Value * 0.1 / 1.1
    Else
       .Cells(rowCount, 9).Value = ""
    End If
    rowCount = rowCount + 1

Loop

End With
End Sub
```